# Magento: setParentBlock from within a layout xml file?

Tags: magento, block, parent

There exists

```
public Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::setParentBlock(Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block)
```

Evidently it takes a block object as an argument. I have tried:

```
<reference name="myBlock">
    <action method="setParentBlock">
        <block><reference name="newParent"/></block>
    </action>
</reference>
```

But, no luck. 
Any ideas?
Is it even possible to someone pass a block object to a method, from within a layout file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call that method from layout XML files.  The layout XML file's `<action/>` node is mainly (see below) used to pass strings as parameters.  That means any method where the type hint explicitly requires an object

```
Mage_Core_Block_Abstract $block
```

is not meant to be called from the XML.  It's a method used in the implementation of the system, and one the layout XML system is meant to protect you from accidentally calling.

Also, you can't use reference in the way you're trying

```
<reference name="newParent"/>
```

The `<reference/>` tag is only valid as an immediate ancestor of the top level layout handles (any other behavior caused by using reference in another location is an unintended implementation side effect, and I'd be wary of relying on said behavior)

Finally, you *may* be able to achieve what you want by using the "helper parameter" feature of the layout system.

```
<action method="setParentBlock">
    <block helper="core/data/someMethod" arg1="foo" ...>
</action>
```

if you can find a helper class

```
Mage::helper('core/data');
```

Where `someMethod` returns the block you're after

```
Mage::helper('core/data')->someMethod(parameters,from,attributes,above);
```

but changing a block's parent mid-render is sort of abusing the layout system, and I'd advise against it (unless there's no other way to get at what you want).

Comment: Your absolutly right, and I say that after tracing how it works.. :). Although, is it REALLY mid-render? I'm not sure. It is strange that I cannot take an already defined layout block and, simply, relocate it by means of choosing another parent name. It's not really essential, but it would have been more elegant.

Comment: @dror See Ben's answer below — also, see `unsetChild` and `setChild`.  That's usually how people achieve what you just described in your comment.  And yes, it really is mid render.

Comment: In my particular case the blocks in the base layouts do not have alias/as attributes.. So I can't really use un/setChild..

Comment: @Dror A block's name should be sufficient there if there's no alias set.

Answer (score 3):

You needn't worry about this at all, as the inverse is typically the way associations are built, but if you want to set a parent you can use the `parent` block attribute:

```
<block type="..." name="..." parent="parentblockname" ... />
```

Comment: if I take this approach, having, another block is already defined in exactly the same way, except without an explicit parent name (But inside another parent), what would be the outcome? Perhaps both would be registered? Or maybe only the parent of the single block will be updated upon processing your suggestion (What I'm aiming for :)?

Comment: Not sure I follow, but, the parent block will need to be created. Keep in mind that the important thing in Magento rendering is the parent having the child set on it via insert or setChild, because that is the "direction" of rendering - parent to child.